# Reduce spacing between two clipped images

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I am using clip-path to clip two images. The result is

[image]

Everything is fine but I want to reduce the spacing between these images just like this

[image]

```css
.clip-wrap {
  display: inline;
}
.element {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 60% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 60% 100%);
}
.element2 {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="clip-wrap">
  <img src="http://karenmenezes.com/shapes-polygon/clip-demo.jpg" alt="demo-clip-css" class="element" width="150" height="150">
</div>
<div class="clip-wrap">
  <img src="http://karenmenezes.com/shapes-polygon/clip-demo.jpg" alt="demo-clip-css" class="element2" width="150" height="150">
</div>
```

[JsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/vd5ezk7z/1/)

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with negative `margin-left` on second elementi?

Comment: About 50px should do the trick. https://jsfiddle.net/vd5ezk7z/2/

Comment: Note that the code in the question doesn't work in IE11, Edge or FF. It works in Chrome. (Didn't test Safari.)

Comment: Tested on iPad. It works in Safari, as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add

```
 margin-right: -50px;
```

to .element

more explanation :
you an either give a negative margin-right to .element or give a negative margin-left to .element2

Answer (score 3):

The distance between the images is determined by their containers, not the images themselves.

[image]

With a negative margin on the second container, you can shift it closer to the first image.

```css
.clip-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.clip-wrap:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.element {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 60% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 60% 100%);
}
.element2 {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="clip-wrap">
  <img src="http://karenmenezes.com/shapes-polygon/clip-demo.jpg" alt="demo-clip-css" class="element" width="150" height="150">
</div>
<div class="clip-wrap">
  <img src="http://karenmenezes.com/shapes-polygon/clip-demo.jpg" alt="demo-clip-css" class="element2" width="150" height="150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the css clip-paths properties to the wrap elements. Then those wrap elements will be positioned absolute, one to the left and one to the right.
Those wrap elements are inside a container, and the with of the container determines the spacing between the wrap elements.

```
.clips-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}
.clip-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}
.clip-wrap1 {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 60% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 100%, 0 0, 100% 0, 60% 100%);
  left: 0;
}

.clip-wrap2 {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(40% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  right: 0;
}
```

I made changes to your fiddle, take a look: 
https://jsfiddle.net/iamgutz/tfqdksnn/